# I enter a command in visual studio code, namely in javascript let a = 10 or 2+2 and visual code does not respond

Tags: javascript

I enter a command in visual studio code, namely in javascript let a = 10 or 2+2 and visual code does not respond to me at all, that is, it is not underfined and not 4. What am I doing wrong? code runner is installed, node js is also installed. Tell me please[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8SmU6.png)

I enter a command in visual studio code, namely in javascript let a = 10 or 2+2 and visual code does not respond to me at all, that is, it is not underfined and not 4. What am I doing wrong? code runner is installed, node js is also installed. Tell me please

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

VS Code will not run your file itself; you need to execute this command in your terminal to run your file.

```
node yourFileName.js
```

Comment: in which terminal Node js or visual code

Comment: I entered the command but nothing happens, for example console.log('hellow world') produces a response, but 3+2 produces nothing

Comment: Because you have to `console.log` it. If you don't, you're just throwing that expression away.